# Implementing a job scheduler for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, webserver, scheduled-tasks

I need to execute some **activities/jobs** in my Web Server, such as indexing some information, organizing some files, and calculating some statistics...

I want to preserve the QoS in my Web Server (performance, memory consumption, ...). So I'm thinking of **executing an external process** for these activities, instead of calling in a thread. Something similar to  [Apache MPM processer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/worker.html) (it launches child processes to process the requests).

- Do know any best solution to do this?
- Do you know any library that could do this for me?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally implemented a system to execute tasks/jobs in a external process.

If someone want to know how I implemented it, here are some of the details. Maybe I will write an article to share the solution and the source code.

Basically, we have two components, the `Web.dll` (ASP.NET application) and a program called `TaskExecutor.exe`

In the `Web.dll`, there is an activity scheduler that can register tasks by name: for example:

```
ActivityScheduler.Get().RegisterActivity("GenerateSearchIndexes", 4 * 1000 * 60 * 60); //each 2 hours
```

The activity scheduler executes each activity in a thread, and this thread calls an external process, the `ActivityExecutor.exe`

This assembly has a reference to the `Web.dll` that has a static ActivityFactory to get the activities. The source code of the external process is quite simple:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No activity name given", "ActivityName");
        }
        //parameter 0 is the activity name
        string activityName = args[0];
        IScheduledActivity activity = ActivityFactory.GetActivity(activityName);

        if (activityName != null)
        {
            activity.Execute(args);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error executing activity: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

As you can guess the restriction here is that the activities must be statically defined, so they cannot receive paramenters in its constructor. The are passed in the `IScheduledActivity.Schedule(string[] args)` method, in the same way as a program would do.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to schedule jobs which will run on the server.

Comment: I'm reading the doc ... Can Quartz execute Jobs in separate processes?

Comment: @Daniel, Quartz executes jobs, those jobs can spawn processes: `Process.Start("foo.exe");`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like they use on the Stack Exchange sites?

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Comment: But this is a threaded alternative, I'm looking for something that is able to launch a proccess to execute my Job. Thanks anyway.